# Cyrillic letters not displaying in PDF generated by pdftk

Tags: php, laravel, fpdf, pdftk, php-pdftk

The problem is that Cyrillic letters not displaying in PDF form created with `pdftk`, specifically using  [mikehaertl/php-pdftk](https://github.com/mikehaertl/php-pdftk) package:

[image: MacOS Google Chrome latest (56.0.2924.87 (64-bit)]

When clicked, the symbols are displaying:

[image]

In Windows 10 Acrobat Reader similar file looks like this:

[image: Windows 10 Acrobat Reader Cyrillyc symbols not displaying correctly]

Here is the code:

```
$pdf = new \mikehaertl\pdftk\Pdf(public_path("demo_form_template.pdf"));

$values = [
  "name" => "МНОГОКРАТНАЯ",
  "address" => "English text",
];

$pdf->fillForm($values)
    ->needAppearances()
    ->saveAs(public_path('demo_form_filled.pdf');
```

To summarise, when opened in

- MacOS Google Chrome - displays not correctly
- MacOS Acrobat Reader - displays OK
- Windows 7 Acrobat Reader - displays OK
- Windows 10 Acrobat Reader - displays not correctly
- Ubuntu Acrobat Reader - displays not correctly

Any ideas? Should I consider another solution to generate PDFs? Or may be consider `fpdf` or other?